# Restrict Bootstrap range slider draggers to stay on the same value

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I'm using the Bootstrap range slider in one of my projects. What I need to do is not to allow the left and right draggers to be on the same value. Can anybody give me a hint on how can this be done? The Bootstrap slider can be seen over here: http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-slider/

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share a link to `Bootstrap range slider`?  Or share a fiddle?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my question with a link to that plugin.

Comment: So you you are just looking at making it so the sliders can't be on the same value?  Or are you looking to not have them cross either?

Comment: I want to restrict them stay on the same value. I want them cross though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ex2").slider({});
    $('#ex2').slider()
      .on('slideStop', function(ev){
          var adjustValue1 = 15;
          var adjustValue2 = 0;
          if(ev.value[0] == ev.value[1]){
              if($('#ex2').data('slider-min') + adjustValue1 > ev.value[0]){
                  adjustValue1 = 0;
                  adjustValue2 = 15;
              }
              $('#ex2').slider('setValue',[ev.value[0]-adjustValue1,ev.value[1]+adjustValue2]);  // if equal change value
          }
      });
    $('#ex2').slider()
      .on('slide', function(ev){
          $('#left').text(ev.value[0]);
          $('#right').text(ev.value[1]);
      });
});
```

Example

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/fZD67/1/

Something to work off of.